# Not able to connect sonar central server from a gradle springboot project

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to run sonar central server https://sonar.company.com/ from my gradle project. i am getting below error "**SonarQube server [https://sonar.company.com] can not be reached**".

My Gradle task

```
sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.projectKey", "key"
    property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonar.company.com"
    property "sonar.login", "347823rywejfsdjhfjsd8fsdjhf"
}
```

}